# How to disable all hyperlinks, until all lightbox were loaded using javascript or jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I disable all the hyperlinks, till the `lightbox` gets loaded. Because before the `lightbox-js` get loaded, if I click on the hyperlink then it gets redirected to the HTML page rather than showing in the lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `bind()` and `unbind()`.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

After the lightbox gets loaded, use this:

```
$('a').unbind('click');
```

Comment: And you're going to check when lightbox is loaded how?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy If the function to initialise the lightbox(es) isn't asynchronous (and I don't see why it would be), simply calling `.unbind()` after that should work.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working for the hyperlinks that redirects to lightbox.

Comment: Can you please put your code so that we can play around. It is no way gonna help you if you keep your code inside. :)